# The algorithm "bcrypt" is not supported. Symfony

Tags: symfony

Symfony does't work with bcrypt algorithm, it's so strange anyone know what could be ?
Thanks.

```
security:
   encoders:
    AppBundle\Entity\Usuario:
      algorithm: bcrypt
```

The app says me

> The algorithm "bcrypt" is not supported.

Comment: Which version of php are you using? You need php 5.5 or above

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php

Comment: Solution not found yet :(

Comment: What symfony do you use? It should explicitly create an instance of `BCryptPasswordEncoder` if `bcrypt` is specified.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please put this code in somewhere to make sure you can run bcrypt algorithm for hashing password

```
$encoder = new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\BCryptPasswordEncoder(4);
$password = $encoder->encodePassword('your_plain_password', 'your_salt');
```

If you receive error like `To use the BCrypt encoder, you need to upgrade to PHP 5.5 or install the "ircmaxell/password-compat" via Composer.`. So unfortunately, I think you should reinstall PHP. otherwise, that must be a bug in symfony document. Because I've just had a check the PHP function `hash_algos()`, it doesn't return bcrypt algorithm, strange! My PHP version is 5.6.11

Answer (score 0):

Finaly "fixed", I've reinstaled the symfony version, I had a old version.
Thanks all for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use  AppBundle\Entity\Usuario:

```
security:
   encoders:
      App\Entity\User:
         algorithm: bcrypt
```